# creating a development branch with git

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a fairly simple setup for a web page. The development work is done on my personal computer. When I'm happy with what I have, I push to bitbucket. Then, I go to my production server, issue `git pull origin master` and everything works nicely.

As the application matures, I need to create a development (or rather, staging) branch that is also available on the web server, attaches to its own database and can be used to test new features.

So, what I (think) I want to do is create a new branch called `staging`, and have that occupy a separate directory on the webserver. I will have a .gitignore'd environment file that tells it how to access the staging database.

Once I'm happy with changes I made on my development machine, I'll push them to staging. Then, once they have been tested in the "real" world, I'll merge the changes into master and the production server will enjoy all the updates.

Now, my questions:

1. How do I create a new branch that is essentially a copy of master?
2. How do I create a new directory on the web server to hold this branch without affecting the master branch which is in another directory?
3. How do I merge the staging branch into the master branch without destroying the staging branch?

Please note that I have read https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/ but I can not figure out the git commands that I need in order to make it all work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do I create a new branch that is essentially a copy of master?

Assuming you are currently on the `master` branch, you do this by running:

```
git checkout -b staging
```

That creates a new branch named `staging` that is based on your current branch.

> How do I create a new directory on the web server to hold this branch without affecting the master branch which is in another directory?

The easiest way is simply to create another clone of your repository and then check out the `staging` branch.  For example:

```
git clone https://git.example.com/my/project staging
cd staging
git checkout staging
```

You can reduce this by one step by using the `-b` argument to `git clone`:

```
git clone -b staging https://git.example/com/my/project staging
```

In either case, you end up with a directory named "staging" that contains a checkout of the `staging` branch from your repository.

An alternative approach is to use [git worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree), but I think that ends up being more complex.

> How do I merge the staging branch into the master branch without destroying the staging branch?

You would typically do this on your local host by first checking out the `master` branch and then merging the `staging` branch:

```
git checkout master
git merge staging
```

A lot of this is covered in [The Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2); you may want to read through that if you haven't already.